# Подключение R к DB ORA -12560

Tags: r, odbc

Получаю ошибку `ORA - 12560` when I try connect to Oracle DB installed on VM.

> sql*plus, pl/sql, excel - connect successfully

Код подключения в R :

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver ='Oracle in instantclient_19_14',
dns = "user", encoding = "windows-1251",PWD ="qazedcwsx")
#--- output Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: IM006: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

> sql*plus могу подключиться только если после пароля пропишу `@sid`, в R этот метод не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
.connection_string = "Driver={Oracle in nstantclient_19_14};Dbq=XE;Uid=user;Pwd=qazedcwsx;)
```